# Angular Unit Testing: Why my expect(1).toBe(2) always passes?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have figured out that probably my test is never getting executed. Because the color of the test description in the output is neither green nor red. 
May be I am wrong. 
I have also figured out that it works fine if I comment out `component.ngOnInit();`
I am providing all of my spec file code without leaving out anything that could be the problem.

[image]

**SPEC**

```
class AppConstantsStub {
  public userPreferences = {
    modelData: {
      basicDetails: {
        itemId: 3 // some other valid value here is fine
      }
    },
    UserBasicDetails: {
      // some valid values here, maybe
    }
  };
}
class ComponentDetailsServiceStub {
  defaultProperties = {
    editable: false,
    showToolbar: false,
    viewMode: false,
    editMode: false,
    showPopup: true,
    formSavedClicked: false,
    cancelClicked: false,
    refresh: false,
   };

  push(value){
    this.propertiesSource.next(value);
  }
  private propertiesSource = new BehaviorSubject(this.defaultProperties);
  currentProperties = this.propertiesSource.asObservable();



  setDefaultCancelClicked() { }
}
class SearchAPIServiceStub {


}
class UOMServiceStub { }
class BomDetailsServiceStub { }
class FormBuilderUtilsServiceStub { }
class DMServiceStub { }
class GlobalLoaderServiceStub {
  hideLoader() { }
}
class SCNotificationServiceStub { }
class CreateRfxServiceStub { }
class LayoutServiceStub { }
class GridFilterServiceStub {
  searchConfig() { return null; }
}

describe('component details', () => {
  let componentDetailsComponent: ComponentDetailsComponent;
  let subject: ComponentDetailsComponent;
  let formBuilderUtilsService: FormBuilderUtilsService;
  let appConstants: AppConstants;
  let componentDetailsService: ComponentDetailsServiceStub;
  let dMService: DMService;
  let globalLoaderService: GlobalLoaderServiceStub;
  let sCNotificationService: SCNotificationService;
  let createRfxService: CreateRfxService;
  let layoutService: LayoutService;
  let gridFilterService: GridFilterService;

  let mode: string;

  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ComponentDetailsComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ComponentDetailsComponent],
      providers: [

        { provide: FormBuilderUtilsService, useClass: FormBuilderUtilsServiceStub },
        { provide: AppConstants, useClass: AppConstantsStub },
        { provide: ComponentDetailsService, useClass: ComponentDetailsServiceStub },
        { provide: DMService, useClass: DMServiceStub },
        { provide: GlobalLoaderService, useClass: GlobalLoaderServiceStub },
        { provide: SCNotificationService, useClass: SCNotificationServiceStub },
        { provide: CreateRfxService, useClass: CreateRfxServiceStub },
        { provide: LayoutService, useClass: LayoutServiceStub },
        { provide: GridFilterService, useClass: GridFilterServiceStub },

      ],

      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    });
    // subject = TestBed.get(ComponentDetailsComponent);

      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ComponentDetailsComponent);
      subject = fixture.componentInstance;
       componentDetailsService = TestBed.get(ComponentDetailsService);
     fixture.detectChanges();
  });
  it('should create componentDetailsComponent', () => {
    expect(1).toBe(2);
  });


}
);
```

Comment: Could you reduce this to the minimal amount of code needed to reproduce the error?

Comment: In other words, if you had an empty spec file and just had `expect(1).toBe(2);` would you get the same result?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker No I wouldnt. I am getting this only in this code. I tried to minimize the code and I figured out that everything works fine until i add `     fixture.detectChanges(); 
` . And its only with this particular code.